# Fastest way to transfer files between servers

Tags: file-transfer

I am attempting to transfer a 8 GB tar file from one cpanel server to another.

I have root access on the new server and jailed shell on the old. I attempted to `wget` and `curl` but I am getting speeds less than 200KB/s which is horrible and going to take up to 14 hours.

Is there a faster method? Would `scp` or `rsync` increase the download speed on the new server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a faster method.. would scp or rsync increase the download
>   speed on the new server.

`scp` would not be any faster - there would be a slight overhead of the secure connection, but its negligible.

`rsync` would only be faster if you already had some files on the destination server - that way you aren't copying everything wholesale. However in your case I believe you are provisioning a new server so rsync would not provide any significant gains.

It sounds like there is some throttling or bandwidth restriction on your old server; because your limits seem artificial; explicitly restricted rather that a physical connection limitation. I would suggest talking with your NOC support to see if they can do anything about the restrictions or as mdpc said, use the old fashioned method. Ask your NOC to create a backup (simply cloning the disk would be fastest, burning DVDs quite slower) and then have it couriered over to your new data center.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes believe it or not the best answer is cut a tape/USB/CD/DVD (or whatever) and use FED-EX to the remote site...or if local walk over and feed it into the new server.

Comment: +1 for [Sneakernet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sneakernet). -1 He almost certainly doesn't have physical access to the machines to actually do this.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you try CURL? It might be faster.

Here is the Wikipedia page on CURL: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL

I think this is the command you need:

```
curl -O www.example.com/file.tar.gz
```

Comment: -1 "I attempted to wget and **curl**"

Comment: I'm not sure how curl would be faster, seems that its a physical limitation on the network.